# How good or bad of a fit would this question about international human rights law have been here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I just asked a question at Expatriates SE called

[Could one renounce one's native citizenship in order to prevent a second, naturalized citizenship from being revoked?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/11767/9674)

I contemplated posting it on another SE instead, for example Politics SE or Law SE.

Would it have fit better (or worse) here?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a question about a legal decision by an individual person in order to evade a judicial action by a court. It is not about a political action made by a government or politician. That means it would likely be a fitting question for Law.SE.

The general rule of thumb for deciding if a question about laws belongs to Politics.SE or Law.SE is this:

- Law.SE is about "What is the law?"
- Politics.SE is about "Why is this the law?"
- If it is about a law which is explicitly about political processes (like "Is it legal to bribe a congressman to vote against a bill?"), you can ask it on either site.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, questions about international law (as opposed to "comparative law") are usually questions that are more appropriate at Politics.SE, even if they pertain to individuals, because international law is a highly political matter.

I am also quite dismayed at the knee jerk closing of a question like [Was the bombing of Hiroshima/Nagasaki a war crime?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/was-the-bombing-of-hiroshima-nagasaki-a-war-crime) as Off-Topic or Opinion based, simply because one can advocate for more than one possible answer to the question. This seems like a well formed question that is pretty much perfect for Politics.SE in my view.

Let readers and people voting on answers decide which is better if conflicting answers to the same question are offered.

Questions are routinely closed and placed on hold inappropriately in Politics.SE for reasons that are not consistent and sensible.

In the case of questions about international law, the close votes seem to reflect the misguided assumption that one can not make meaningful and well supported statements about international law in general.